# Yes, it does answer the question

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

The question was "Did personal computers ever support 8" floppies?" so obviously stating that mine did IS an answer to the question.  Don't like the answer, downvote.  Think I'm lying, say so (if that's possible to do without violating the 'be nice' policy).

But why claim the obvious isn't there and delete?

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of transparency, here's the answer that I unilaterally voted to delete:

> When I had to move from New York in 1995, I chose to not take my S-100 nor its two eight-inch drives.

That is the answer in its entirety, answering the question:

> Did personal computers ever support 8" floppies?

---

I mean, it does *sort of* provide some information that could perhaps be used to deduce that the Altair 8800 could be connected to an 8-inch floppy drive, but... really? I had to use both knowledge I've absorbed from this site *and* three different web pages to figure that out. If you'd provided more information in your answer then perhaps I wouldn't have deleted it, but you've used over 2.5x the number of words in this question than in your answer!

And now I'm going to tackle a few misleading parts of your meta question:

> so obviously stating that mine did IS an answer to the question.

This is a true statement, but it implies that *your* answer stated that your computer had two eight-inch floppy drives. It includes that information, yes, but the focus of the sentence (the entire answer, even!) is on you moving from New York and not taking your computer.

> But why claim the obvious isn't there

It's not obviously there; the only mention of an 8-inch drive is in the final three words. And for all I knew, the S-100 could've been an IBM mainframe machine, or perhaps a terminal; there was no context to say that it was a board included in personal computers and not something other than a personal computer.

By all means feel free to improve your answer, and I'll vote to undelete it. But the answer you originally posted was... not really an answer at all.

Comment: The name of the site is retro-computing.  Why would it occur to me that fans of such would not know what S-100 is?  S-100 is not a board used in computers, it is/was a type of computer.

Comment: @WGroleau S-100 is a family of boards, first used in the Altair 8800 and subsequently in various other machines. Like the later IBM PC, it was a standard of its day. After standardisation (and to an extent before) you could swap around various S-100-compatible components to put together a machine capable of doing what you wanted (e.g. talking to a printer). Here's a copy of the standard: http://www.imsai.net/download/IEEE_696_1983.pdf One board would usually contain the bulk of the machine, from what I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but your post is **at best** Me-Too level, and does not tell anything about type and manufaturer, or if it was instead some homebrew configuration. After all, the fact that an 8" can be connected wasn't asked. That has even be done with todays AVRs. RC isn't Kindergarden (even if it feels like sometimes) where everyone  shouts to get a candy.

Bottom line: There have been several answers written before giving more detailed information about standard usage of 8" on micro/personal computers, posting an 'I had one' in addition doesn't add anything useful for the audience.

Comment: Fair enough.  And perhaps reason to delete.  But saying it didn’t answer the question wasn’t true.